# find user email in the session of `devise`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I succeeded to find out the id of the user that signed in, by:

```
#{session['warden.user.user.key'][1][0]}
```

how can I get the email that the user signed in with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get email from **current_user** object when you already signed in using devise

`current_user.email`